# How to remove child/sprites on button press?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, actionscript

I am working on a project where, if the user clicks "grow a garden", it will generate a random number of flowers and a random number of weeds. Once they have completed their 'growing' sequence, the user is presented with a "Grow a New Garden" in which the flowers/weeds will be deleted from the stage and start anew.

I have racked my brain and this is the closest I have come to "removing the children" - a concept I have never understood haha. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

** Edited Code as I copied the old file**

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

// stops the playhead on frame 1
stop();

// random amount of flowers generated
var flowerAmount:int = (Math.ceil((Math.random() * 20)) + 9);
var weedAmount = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 10));


// garden display container
var newGarden:DisplayObjectContainer;

// setting new flower variable equal to the function that creates an instance of the flower
var newFlower_mc:DisplayObject = newFlower();

// flowers currently in the garden
var flowersInGarden:int = 0;
var weedsInGarden:int = 0;


// event listener for the grow button to start the garden
grow_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, frameTwo);

// when grow button is clicked go to frame two
function frameTwo(event:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}

// changes the size and position of the flower
function configureFlower(myFlower_mc:DisplayObject) {
    myFlower_mc.x = Math.random() * 400;
    myFlower_mc.y = Math.random() * 200;
    var flowerSize:Number = Math.random() + .5;
    myFlower_mc.height = myFlower_mc.height * flowerSize;
    myFlower_mc.width = myFlower_mc.width * flowerSize;
}
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

// function to create new instance of a flower
function newFlower():DisplayObject {
    var newFlower_mc:DisplayObject = new flower();
    return newFlower_mc;
}

// function to call the create flower function and add flower to sprite 
function createFlower() {
    var myFlower_mc = newFlower();
        configureFlower(myFlower_mc);
        newGarden.addChild(myFlower_mc);
    trace(flowerAmount);
    }

newGarden = new Sprite();

// adds the flower to the stage/sprite and adds to the flower counter
    function showFlowers() {
    createFlower();
    addChild(newGarden);
    flowersInGarden++;
    trace("Flowers:" + flowersInGarden + " " + weedAmount + " weedsingarden" + weedsInGarden);


}
// calls the above function
showFlowers();


// function to create a weed, configure weed and add to the garden sprite
function createWeed(){ 
    var newWeed:DisplayObject; 
    trace("creating weed"); 
    newWeed = new weed(); 
    newGarden.addChild(newWeed); 
    configureFlower(newWeed);
    weedsInGarden++;
}// if all the flowers haven't grown yet, go back to frame 2 until they have

if (flowersInGarden < flowerAmount) {
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}

// if the amount of weeds decided haven't grown yet, create another weed

if (weedsInGarden < weedAmount){ createWeed(); };
stop();

// event listener to grow a new garden
new_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, growNewGarden);


// function to create a new garden if there are more than 1 instance in the container
function growNewGarden(event:MouseEvent) {
    while (newGarden.numChildren > 0) {
    stage.removeChild(newFlower_mc); 
        stage.removeChild(newGarden);
        // add a new, fresh sprite
        stage.addChild(newGarden);
        // randomly chooses a number of flowers
        flowerAmount = (Math.ceil((Math.random() * 21)) + 10);
        // resets flower counter to zero
        flowersInGarden = 0;
    gotoAndPlay(2);

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use the `numChildren` property as your property to loop through, you should be using the child index as the variable in the loop to select the children.  What you have done is you're looping through the children and trying to remove something called `newFlower_mc` or something like that, and that variable doesn't mean anything in the scope of that function. It might look like this

```
for (var i:int = newGarden.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    var f:DisplayObject = newGarden.getChildAt(i);
    f.parent.removeChild(f);
}
```

so that's one way.

I think it would be much simpler to just remove the garden though, and since all the weeds and flowers are children of the garden, they will also be removed. Simply:

```
newGarden.parent.removeChild(newGarden);
```

voila!

Also, just a side note about your `var newFlower_mc = newFlower();`. I'm not sure you understand what that is doing. It's not setting a variable equal to a function. It is setting that variable equal to the output or the result of that function being called one time. That line of code does this:

1. Declares a variable with a unique name called `newFlower_mc`.
2. Calls the constructor function `newFlower()` which returns a `DisplayObject`
3. Sets that returned DisplayObject instance to the variable `newFlower_mc`

That's all well and good, but you have a problem. Later, in your constructor function if `newFlower`, you declare another variable... with a name that is already in use... `newFlower_mc`. This is bad. I have no idea what the result is. If flash is somehow allowing this to compile and run without errors I'm surprised, but at any rate it is bad practice. I think it comes from you not understanding what happens when you set a variable `=` a function. I hope my explanation helped.

Comment: I took the code from a previous example in my textbook, so perhaps I misapplied it.

I will have a look in the morning - thank you for taking time out of your day to give a detailed answer - much appreciated!